# Edit XML on Server via Service

Tags: c#, xml, winapi, servicestack

Currently, I have a web based C# application (ServiceStack) that has an XML file it relies on to generate things client side. I no longer want to store this file on the client side. I need a way to use the repository I wrote to edit the file when it is stored on the server.

I have tried the following:

- Finding the file location of XML when in the service. (it says that the service current directory is windows/system32, because it's running as a service. Makes sense now.)
- Putting the file in the same project side by side. (same problem)

This already works:

- Retrieves XML ( With hard coded path :c )
- Deserialize XML
- Add/Remove to XML as needed
- Save

The key thing to this problem is it must live where the API lives. I don’t think that I am understanding the way this works very well, and I'd greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath` to find the path of the file relative to your application, assuming it's hosted via IIS.

Comment: I get this error "The relative virtual path '../Project.API/OptionPresets.xml' is not allowed here." What path do I even pass into this? Not the static path of where it's located on the server right?

Comment: Try changing it to ```~/OptionPresets.xml```.

Comment: It works! but only if it's in the same project. Do you know how I can go one level up? System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~../Projcet.API/OptionPresets.xml"); doesn't work.

Comment: Found this answer out, you can not go up a level in the folder structure when using MapPath because of security reasons. It makes sense. If you were in need of it though and were not concerned with security I'm sure some kind of string.replace would work just fine. Although it's kind of hacky.

Answer (score 1):

In ServiceStack you'd normally use the [Virtual File System](http://docs.servicestack.net/virtual-file-system) to resolve files, e.g:

```
base.VirtualFileSources.GetFile("path/to/file.xml").ReadAllText()
```

Otherwise if you just want the path you can use `IAppHost.MapProjectPath()` available from v4.5.4 to [resolve a file path relative to your WepApp consistently in all App Hosts](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.2#mapprojectpath), e.g:

```
HostContext.AppHost.MapProjectPath("~/path/to/file.xml")
```

Comment: What namespace does "base" come from I have no reference to it. As far as the HostContext.AppHost.MapProjectPath("~/path/to/file.xml") i cannot use because i need to use a slightly older version of ServiceStack due to licensing. But thanks for the input.

Comment: @BillyCostanza You can use base from in your ServiceStack Service implementation, otherwise you can access it from HostContext.VirtualFileSources

Comment: I don't think that VitualFileSources is a part of ServiceStack 3.9.71 so unfortunately that won't work, but perhaps will for someone else.

Comment: @BillyCostanza Note for v3.9.71 you should use the **servicestack-bsd** tag instead to make it clear which version you're referring to. In v3 the VFS was called VirtualPathProvider

Comment: VirtualPathProvider has .OpenFile which is a way of reading the file not getting the path as a string. Still helpful but not quite what I was looking for. I will keep the tag in mind for next time, thank you.